# Wordpress page grouping

Tags: wordpress, grouping

Is there any way to group/folder my pages in Wordpress. Pages as in pages, not posts. In case I'm using it as a CMS and have, say, 200 pages. 10 main pages and the rest are all sub-pages. It'd be really inconvenient to see all the pages as a one huge lists.

I know I could use posts and categories, as I won't be needing the blog functionality anyway, and even if I did need it, I could make it work anyway. Thing is, I'd lose a bit functionality this way and it's unfortunately not an option for me.

I have looked around and Googled but so far with no results. I'm sure I'm not the only one who has come to wonder about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I found exactly what I was looking for.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/page-tree/

> Do you have a WordPress site with lots of pages in a hierarchical structure? Are you trying to use WordPress like a "real" CMS? Then this plugin is for you!
>   Page Tree gives you a much-needed overview of your pages in the admininstration panel using a common expand/collapse menu, which lets you navigate your page structure like a folder tree in Windows Explorer.

Comment: Pretty interesting. You could check your own answer as accepted since you solved your problem by yourself, it could help other users in SO.

Answer (score 1):

**CMS Tree Page View** is a plugin that I've created and I think it's what you've been looking for.

Some of it's features are:

- View and organize pages in a simple to use tree view
- Edit pages directly from the tree
- Add pages at any place in the tree
- Drag and drop to rearrange your pages
- Search pages
- See all pages  – including private and drafts – or just publicly available pages

Screenshots, a screencast and download:
http://eskapism.se/code-playground/cms-tree-page-view/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are trying to do, this is supported in wordpress core since the page is able to have a subpages and so on.

More info about pages organization on the following link:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Organizing_Your_Pages

Comment: Yeah, I know that. What I meant is that, once I have all those 200 pages, 10 parent pages, each with 20 child-pages... how am I able to collapse and expand the child-pages of parent-pages. Say, I want to only see the child-pages of the 5th parent page... I don't need see all the other 9 parent-pages' child-pages, it'd be just insane seeing a 2 miles long list of pages. Do you know what I mean? Sorry for not explaining myself clearly enough. I said "pages" 10 times. :/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [WordPress › pageMash > Page Management « WordPress Plugins?](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/pagemash/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php 
global $post; $current_page_parent = ( $post->post_parent ? $post->post_parent : $post->ID );

$mypages = get_pages( array (
    'sort_order'    => 'ASC',
    'sort_column'   => 'post_title',
    'hierarchical'  => 1,
    'child_of'      => $current_page_parent,
    'number'        => 5,
    'offset'        => 0,
    'post_type'     => 'page',
    'post_status'   => 'publish' ) );

?><ul class="sibling-page-list">
<li class="page-text">Page: </li>
<?php
$iPage = 0;
foreach( $mypages as $page ) {
    $iPage++;
    // this is to show a highlight of the page you're on.
    if ($post->ID == $page->ID) {$active = "active";} else {$active = "";}
    ?>
    <li class="sibling-page-link <?php echo $active; ?>">
        <a href="<?php echo get_page_link( $page->ID ); ?>" title="<?php echo $page->post_title; ?>"><?php echo $iPage; ?></a>
    </li>
    <?php
}           
?>      
</ul>
```

My stylesheet classes are:

```
.sibling-page-list {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    height: 20px;
}
.sibling-page-list li {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.sibling-page-list li.sibling-page-link.active {
    background: #eee;
}
```

I'll be making a plugin to facilitate this solution since I've had the need for it for quite some time now.

Special thanks to this post: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/list-only-page-siblings which got me started on the top part. The pagination, I added. Also, will be working on how many pages to show, etc... Enjoy modifying it.

Oh, BTW, place this code above in your Page Template file for it to work on pages.